# How to get all nodes from a http post from iphone in Asp?

Tags: iphone, asp.net, vb.net, http-post

I just want to catch evry node in the xml post from the iphone, for example this is the xml file that i need to  "get"

```
<Matchs>
   <owner>Me</owner>
   <typeAction>Me</typeAction>
   <match id=21>sept  3 2011 </match>
   <match id=22>sept  4 2011 </match>
   <match id=23>sept  5 2011 </match>

</Matchs>
```

I'm able to get every node but when there is more than one node with the same name I dont know how to do it...

this is my code to get the values:

```
Public Shared Function TryParse(ByVal value As String, ByRef notification As MatchModel) As Boolean
    Dim success As Boolean = False
    notification = Nothing
    Try
        Dim xReader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(New System.IO.StringReader(value))
        Dim element As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(xReader)
        notification = New MatchModel()
        ' Populate the top XML elements values
        Dim wItem As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = Nothing
        Dim actual As matchAlone = Nothing

        While xReader.MoveToElement()
            If element IsNot Nothing Then
                wItem = element.Element("match")
                actual.Description = GetXElementValue(element, "match")
                actual.Id = GetWorkItemAttributeValue(wItem, "id")
            End If
        End While
        notification.Owner = GetXElementValue(element, "owner")
        notification.TypeAction = GetXElementValue(element, "typeAction")
        success = True
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
    Return success
End Function


Public Shared Function GetXElementValue(ByVal element As System.Xml.Linq.XElement, ByVal name As System.Xml.Linq.XName) As String
    Dim value As String = Nothing
    If element IsNot Nothing Then
        value = element.Element(name).Value
    End If
    Return value
End Function


Public Shared Function GetWorkItemAttributeValue(ByVal element As System.Xml.Linq.XElement, ByVal name As System.Xml.Linq.XName) As String
    Dim value As String = Nothing
    If element IsNot Nothing Then
        value = element.Attribute(name).Value
    End If
    Return value
End Function
```

Please heeeeeelp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim doc as XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(value)
For Each node as XmlNode in doc.SelectNodes("/Matches/Match")
    'Do work
Next
```